# docx4j: how to customize output?

Tags: java, ms-word, xhtml, docx, docx4j

i'm doing some test with docx4j. What i need to do is to convert complex Word documents (2-3 pages of text, tables, bullet list, images) into xhtml.

I took this example: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertOutHtml.java

and it works fine, i have just one concerns, the xhtml produced is much to complicated. I need to simplify it and standardize it to make other transformations, do be done later, easier.

How can i customize the output of specific elements. If i got it right, behind the scenes, OOXML is turned into JAXB and then an xsl is applied to generate the output.

For example, i'd like to have headings outputted as

`<h1>Third heading</h1>` etc...

instead of

```
<p class="Heading1 Normal DocDefaults ">
    <span class="" style="font-family: 'Calibri Light';">Third Heading</span>
</p>
```

Too complex structure and classes i do not need....

Is it possible to change the xsl? Or how can i achieve it without re-implementing thousand of lines of code :)?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is support for using h1, h2 elements but it would be easy enough to add (I did do this some years ago for someone, but its not part of docx4j).  The XHTML output can be produced in 2 ways:

- XSLT + extension functions (where the work is done), or
- a pure Java approach (not quite at feature parity)

Just pick which one approach you want to use/modify.

Note: There is support for this in the XHTML to docx direction: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/in/xhtml/HeadingHandler.java